# Dart - shared preference return null

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working with dart and I had this problem when running my application and in my login it returns null at first in the email and password and the null is shown as text, I'm new to dart, thanks, regards.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZAw8.jpg

```
class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {

  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  bool checkSaveData = false;
  SharedPreferences? pref;

  @override
  void initState() {
    loadSharedPreferences ();
    super.initState();
  }


  loadSharedPreferences () async{
    pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if(pref !=null){
      _emailController.text=pref.getString("email").toString();
      _passwordController.text=pref.getString("password").toString();
      setState(() {});
      print(pref.getString("email"));
      print(pref.getString("password"));
    }

  }
}

                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    TextField(
                                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                        label: Text("Email"),
                                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                      ),
                                      controller: _emailController,
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(
                                      height: 20,
                                    ),
                                    TextField(
                                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                        label: Text("clave"),
                                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                      ),
                                      controller: _passwordController,
                                      obscureText: true,
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(
                                      height: 10,
                                    ),

                                    Consumer<AuthService>(
                                      builder: (context, authServiceProvider, child) {
                                        return SizedBox(
                                          height: 60,
                                          width: double.infinity,
                                          child: authServiceProvider.isLoading
                                              ? const Center(
                                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                          )
                                              : ElevatedButton(
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              authServiceProvider.loginWorker(
                                                  _emailController.text.trim(),
                                                  _passwordController.text.trim(),
                                                  context);

                                              if(checkSaveData && pref !=null){
                                                pref!.setString("email", _emailController.text!);
                                                pref!.setString("password", _passwordController.text!);
                                              }

                                            },
                                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                              //backgroundColor: Colors.tealAccent[600],
                                                backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(114, 153, 160, 10),
                                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30))),
                                            child: const Text(
                                              "LOGIN",
                                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      },
                                    ),

                                    CheckboxListTile(
                                        value: checkSaveData,
                                        title: const Text('save data', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey),),
                                        onChanged: (value) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            checkSaveData=value!;

                                          });
                                        }),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ]))
```

attach an image of the result https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZAw8.jpg

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are calling

```dart
pref.getString("email").toString();
```

If `pref.getString` returns null you are calling `toString()` on null which returns the string `"null"`. If you want it to be empty string instead, you can use the [elvis operator](https://medium.com/@thinkdigitalsoftware/null-aware-operators-in-dart-53ffb8ae80bb):

```dart
pref.getString("email") ?? "";
```

Comment: thanks it works fine.

When I activate the check to save the email and password, it cleans the fields at first, how can I avoid this behavior?